# Can't write different type of items in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to scrape `title`,`description` and `images` from a webpage. The script can fetch them in the right way. The `title` and `desc` are strings but the `images` are in list. Now, I tried to write them in a csv file. However, the issue I'm having is that all the images are stacked in a single row.

***How can I write the existing fields along with all the images in different columns?***

I've tried so far:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amazon.com/Sealect-Designs-Universal-Anchor-Trolly/dp/B01LYUYI8A?ref_=ast_bbp_dp"

def get_content(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    title = soup.select_one("span#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
    desc = soup.select_one("#productDescription > p").get_text(strip=True)
    images = [item.get("src") for item in soup.select("span.a-button-text > img[src$='jpg']")]

    writer.writerow([title,desc,images])
    print(title,desc,images)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("outputfile.csv","w",newline="") as infile:
        writer = csv.writer(infile)
        get_content(url)
```

Current output:

```
column1: title
column2: description
column3: [images]
```

Expected output:

```
column1: title
column2: description
column3: image1
column4: image2
column5: image3
and so on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the star for unpacking the elements of the list images. If you instead write

```
writer.writerow([title,desc,*images])
```

You should get your desired output